# Checkbox value incorrect in custom validation

Tags: 8, forms

I have a custom form like this :

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state){

      $form['first_name'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('First name'),
      ];

      $form['t_and_c_accepted'] =[
         '#type' => 'checkbox',
         '#title'=> t('I accept the terms and conditions'),
         '#return_value' => 1,              
         '#default_value' => 0,
      ];    
 }

public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){

          $values = $form_state->getValues();       
          if(empty($values['first_name'])){
             $form_state->setErrorByName('[first_name]', t('Fill in a first name'));
          }

          if($values['t_and_c_accepted'] !== 1){
             $form_state->setErrorByName('[t_and_c_accepted]', t('Accept the t&c's);
          }
    }
```

1. If I uncheck the checkbox and submit the form, it gives me an error about the unchecked checkbox, as expected.
2. If I check the checkbox, leave the first_name empty and submit the form, it gives me an error that my fist_name is empty, as expected.
3. But if I then fill in first_name, UNcheck the checkbox an submit. The validation passes! So not as expected.
4. If I then go back to the form (back from my landing page), I can reiterate this sequence

I have monitored the `$form_state->getValue('t_and_c_accepted')` value throughout my tests and it gives me indeed `value=1` during the unexpected behavior. So it is consistent with what I see, but I have absolutely no idea what's going on.

So any help would be appreciated

**Update:** 
When looking into the http headers I see that the browser does the POST request with form data `t_and_c_accepted:1` while the checkbox is unchecked.

So Drupal's form api seems to handle the request correct, but why does the browser doesn't post the correct checkbox status value ?

Comment: maybe instead of `!== 1` use `!= 1` or better yet `empty()`?

Comment: valid point, but the problem is that `$form_state->getValue('t_and_c_accepted')` actually returns `1` while it should be `0` if the checkbox is unchecked . So the result of the comparison is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I've found the cause of the issue: 
I rendered `$form['t_and_c_accepted']` twice in the twig template which caused the browser to post a value that was different from the checkbox that was visible.

So it was my own mistake but I answer this question anyway in case anyone else would be wasting time solving the same issue